# Django: create a model with fields derived from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame from which I want to create a model whose fields are the df columns (and sets the right "Field" type for django).

Googled around but could only find bulk_create() tips, which, for my understanding, creates different Models.

My knowledge level: Django tutorial done, trying to exercise by creating this model from a big dataframe (many columns).

EDIT: 
In practice, what I *think* I need is a way to write this part (in a model.py class):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
run_date = models.DateTimeField('run_date')
...
```

in an automatic way by looking at a dataframe with 30+ columns and defining a field for each of them.

I suspect I'm probably thinking it in a wrong way, so I would like some redirection of that kind, if needed.

Comment: do you understand that django model it is just determination of database table, and django does not create the table without migration?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but usually, when creating a model (in a model.py in an app), I define the fields like:

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    run_date = models.DateTimeField('run_date')

then I can call makemigrations etc. 

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to define those fields dynamically

Comment: I'm going to edit the question in order to make it more clear

Comment: You could *probably* override and extend the `ModelBase` metaclass, but it's not built for it and it would most likely not work well. Migrations would most likely break and it would be incredibly fragile to any changes. This is generally a bad idea, if you need to store a dynamic set of columns, then you might want to go with NoSQL or something like that. Otherwise you could create a model with the columns that are static and important and dump the rest of the data in JSON-field, for instance. It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Robert, you are actually shedding some lights on my doubts.

I can give a shot in putting everything else into a JSON-field.

Comment: This how to can help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/legacy-databases/